# how do I return a key-value pair from a database table and render the response in a tabular form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a database table (order's table) that is densely populated with order information as it happens from users with their ids, **and I want to get the sum of fees based on different currencies, and render them as a key-value pair report, at the frontend but in a tabular form**, and I don't even know how to go about it. Below is an example of the table before I proceed

**Orders Table**
[image: order-table]

So how do I craft this such that I will have a comprehensive sum of like currencies and show it in a tablular form in the frontend of the app, such that I have this table below:

**comprehensive summary of like currencies based on sum of whatever existed in the orders table above**
[image: total]

**How do I go about this**? Any help will be appreciated. All am thinking of is a key-value pair logic to render that object on the frontend.

Comment: @theTinMan. Can give an input on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Rails perspective, you need to prepare data that will be rendered in your view. From database perspective, you want to group your orders by currency and sum their charged and network fees. Using a query like this:

```
Order.group(:currency)
     .select("currency, SUM(charged_fee) AS total_charged, SUM(network_fee) AS total_network")
```

If you simply want to render that, assign it to an instance variable inside some action in a controller and use it in a view. You will be able to access your totals by calling

```
order.total_charged
order.total_network
```

for each of the orders.

Hope this makes it clearer for you.

Comment: That sounds interesting. But when I get my result and put it in a different table, how do I now go about filtering that table by date just to see the total_charge_fee and total_network_fee based on date. e.g. filtering to see the total between yesterday and now

Comment: Well, that is definitely out of the scope of your original question. You need to prepare an HTML somewhere on your page where you will allow user to pick dates, route that form to an action in your orders controller and use the date parameter to chain a `.where(date: params[:date])` to the query method above.

Comment: I can do that (filter) but the object won't return datetime in the .group clause you suggested above